# sendkeys.send("{RIGHT}") in datagridviewcell

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, mouseevent, sendkeys

My program crashes when it gets to  `sendkeys.send("{RIGHT}")`

in below code

```
Private Sub dataGridViewDim_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridViewDim.MouseUp

        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            Dim hit As DataGridView.HitTestInfo = _
                DataGridViewDim.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)
            If hit.Type = DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell Then
                DataGridViewDim.BeginEdit(True)
                SendKeys.Send("{RIGHT}") ' crashes when it gets here
            Else
                DataGridViewDim.EndEdit()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Without it works perfectly for single click edit mode. I want to set cursosr all the way to the right.

Comment: I don't recommend using sendkeys for anything really, because there isn't a rock solid guarantee that the keys will be sent to the intended application. For instance if you have 2 apps that happen to both be using sendkeys at the same time, which app gets which keys? If you want a little less worrisome way of doing this, I recommend using the SendMessage api instead, and as a bonus you can send multiple messages to multiple apps regardless of your windowstate, user activity, etc.

Comment: Thanks for useful information. Much appreciated! As my defense it was my first attempt with them and it failed. hah

Answer (score 0):

For reference this did the trick:

```
If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
    Dim hit As DataGridView.HitTestInfo = _
        DataGridViewDim.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)
    If hit.Type = DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell Then
        DataGridViewDim.BeginEdit(True)
        Dim lengstr As Integer = DataGridViewDim.CurrentCell.Value.ToString.Length
        Dim EditBox = DirectCast(DataGridViewDim.EditingControl, TextBox)
        If IsNothing(EditBox) = False Then EditBox.SelectionStart = lengstr
    Else
        DataGridViewDim.EndEdit()
    End If
End If
```